# Why does my displacement map have jaggies

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, displacement

[image]Can someone help me determine why my displacement map has jagged edges. The steps i took in Gimp were black dots on a white background and used a gausian blur filter assuming the black dots would give me the indentation i was looking for, although i'm getting the desired effect the edges contain jaggies[image]

Comment: I should also add that i'm exporting the uv into gimp as a 2049x2049 image but that hasn't seemed to eliminate the jaggies.

Comment: It still could be the pixels that are causing the jaggies.  Is smooth shading on?

Comment: yes sir, i have a subserf applied and smooth shading but as far as the subserf goes i have it set simple instead of ctmul-clark if that matters at all.

Comment: maybe try a higher value in the subsurf subdivisions?

Answer (score 1):

#### First in first, EEVEE is not ready for [fully support of displacement](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/materials/components/displacement.html) in 2.81 and below.

The node connect to displacement socket will become **bump only** solution. And there doesn't exist the **displacement setting block** inside the material panel with EEVEE. When you switch back to cycle, you can choose the type of displacement.

[image]

#### Using cubic interpolation might get the best result in cycles

[image]

Once upon user zoom-in into a ridiculous close place to look into mesh, linear method will become pixelated for some reason(smart will adapt linear in scaling up). But cubic retain smooth detail.

There might be some case that I don't know, so you should try it yourself to test what cause the situation.

Oh, and `2049x2049` might be the worst case that a map can be use in computer graphic. Try to let the map resolution in exponential of 2. e.g. `2048`